# SQL KeyWord Not

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have to make a update which shall change a boolean field in a table. If the value is true the value should be set to false and opposite.

Im not sure how the not keyword works in SQL and the following doesnt seem to work:

`Update tbl set field=!field where ID=1`

Answer (score 3):

The `!` operator is called `NOT` in SQL.  Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET field = NOT field
WHERE ID = 1
```

I have verified that this works on PostgreSQL, and it should work on any DB engine worth its salt.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update tbl set ID=1 where field<>field
```

`<>` is not equal operator in sql

Comment: You cannot `SET` a field "not equal" to anything, in any dialect of SQL with which I am familiar.

Comment: I think OP means logical complement / negation